# Request for addition to the 'This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network' options

Tags: feature-request

The following question is clearly off-topic here but on topic (though very broad) on the *[Language Learning](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/)* site:

[How should English grammar be taught to second-language learners?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/440886/how-should-english-grammar-be-taught-to-second-language-learners)

When voting to close, I would like to have an option to suggest migration to that site. Currently the only options are shown below:

[image]

There have been a few other questions recently that I would like to have suggested for migration.

---

Related Question:

[Proposal to fix the uselessness of the new off-topic close options](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4021/proposal-to-fix-the-uselessness-of-the-new-off-topic-close-options)

Comment: The lack of a button does not stop you from suggesting a migration. What you can do (it's what I do) is 1) "Vote to close as off-topic for 'Other'" and then type in "This question belongs on another site https://languagelearners.stackexchange.com". And then 2) Flag a mod 'Other reason' and ask 'Can this be migrated to Language learners?", and if they see fit, our mods will contact their mods to see if it is a good fit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [traditional guidance for setting default migration paths](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261196) focuses on the level of migration occurring.

> There's no "right" level for establishing a migration path, but tens or hundreds of migrations with a single digit rejection rate seems safe. Single digit migrations in the last 90 days and/or rejection rates that can order a drink without ID are signs that the path will be a waste of time to establish.

While others have pointed out that sites in beta are almost never added as default targets, moderators can still migrate them. And a SEDE query for [questions successfully migrated away](https://data.stackexchange.com/english/query/472000) doesn't make much of a case for LL:

```
Site         Count
ELL           2034
Writers        152
Linguistics     59
SuperUser       18
Philosophy      17
Mathematics     12
User Experience 10 
WebApps          9
Workplace        9
SO               7
```

Right now, LL is in a 4-way tie with Academia, Cognitive Science, and, umm, Graphic Design, with the last successful migration all the way back at 2017-09-05 08:42:41.

If you do come across questions that would be a stronger fit for LL, just [flag them for moderator review](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/8109) as others have suggested, and that will improve the case for the community migration path if and when LL leaves beta.

Comment: Thanks. Your data, along with comments by other responders to my request, have persuaded me that there is currently no need for further action on this issue.

Answer (score 5):

There's very few questions that get migrated to Language Learning, and that's why we do not *need* a dedicated migration path.

For now, flagging the post for a moderator involvement would do just fine. Moderators can migrate it if they see fit.

Plus, Language Learning is in beta, so such migrations are tricky and usually not permitted for us mere mortals.

Comment: You make some good points. What irritates me somewhat however is that when I click '_Off-Topic_' >> '_This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network_', I see the Options dialog whose screenshot I have included in my question. Since neither of the two options apply, I click the X button to close the dialog. But then I am returned to the  question and have to start the 'Close' process again to flag a moderator.

Comment: @Shoe You can click on the breadcrumbs in the title of the closure dialog to move backwards in the selection process instead of quitting the dialog entirely and starting over. (In your screenshot with "Closing > Off-Topic > Migration", both "Closing" and "Off-Topic" are links that take you backwards in the selection process.)

Comment: @Hellion. Thanks for the tip. I'm not sure why this had not occurred to me already!

Answer (score 2):

Beta sites need some space to figure out their identity before we start dropping a lot of questions on them that their community may or may not want. Funneling a bunch of questions to them pollutes the test of whether they are able to build a community around their topic.

Keeping it so that only moderators can migrate ensures that the site isn't buried in questions that folks outside of that community think should belong on the site. Often when a flag to migrate a question comes in, moderators will ask the mod team of the target site if the question will be well-received before migrating it.

We should probably hold off on a migration path until after the site has graduated and the community is more well-defined. That way we will have a much better idea of what does and does not belong there. They might not want questions asking for a list of teaching methods. They might prefer that we just direct the author to the site and encourage them to search there before asking.